# Generate the best possible regexp match

Tags: regex, algorithm, language-agnostic

Given a regexp R, eg `^[a-z]+$` and a string that doesn't match it e.g. `abc-d@e`, how can I generate the longest subset of S that matches (in this case, `abcde`)?

I'm interested in a general solution, for example for `R=/^[0-9]+(?=[a-z])/` and `S=x123a` the algorithm should return `123a`.

In other words, the problem is: what should be removed from a non-matching string so that it matches.

Comment: Shouldn't you then just use `[a-z]+` and then implode the results ? Also, what language are you using ?

Comment: Your question is rather open-ended. If you just want to eliminate everything that doesn't match a particular set of characters, then try `s/[^a-z]+//g`

Comment: Intriguing question, but for a truly universal solution, especially when lookarounds are allowed, including those with full regexes inside them, it's going to be very difficult (short of a brute-force solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think brute force is the only (feasible, without writing one's own regex engine) solution:

```
import itertools
import re

def all_substrings(s):
    for i in reversed(range(len(s))):
         for sequence in itertools.combinations(range(len(s)), i+1):
             yield "".join(s[n] for n in sequence)

def find_longest(s, regex):
    for substring in all_substrings(s):
        if regex.search(substring):
            return substring

print(find_longest("abc-d@e", re.compile(r"^[a-z]+$")))
print(find_longest("x123a", re.compile(r"^[0-9]+(?=[a-z])")))
```

Output:

```
abcde
123a
```